# Specification in Spring JPA, 'not in' Query

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

can't make work `not in` query.
There are tables `User` and `Relation`. Relation contains 2 fields with reference on User: `user` and `other`. I need records from `User` that are not referenced as `Relation.other`.
Trying compose this way:

```
    return (root, query, builder) -> {
        Subquery<Relation> subQuery = query.subquery(Relation.class);
        Root<Relation> subQueryRoot = subQuery.from(Relation.class);
        subQuery.select(subQueryRoot);
        Predicate userPredicate = builder.equal(subQueryRoot.get("user"), user);
        return builder.not(
                builder.in(
                        subQuery.select(subQueryRoot.get("other")).where(userPredicate)
                )
        );
    };
```

but the result is such SQL:

```
        -- othere conditions
        and (
            (
                select
                    relation1_.other_id 
                from
                    relation relation1_ cross 
                join
                    user user2_ 
                where
                    relation1_.other_id=user2_.id 
                    and relation1_.user_id=?
            ) not in  (
                null
            )
        )
```

How to fix it?